# How do I document a custom LLDB command (alias)?

Tags: xcode, gdb, lldb

In GDB (typically in .gdbinit file) I use to document my added custom commands like this :

```
define parg    <-- this define my custom command
p *($arg0*)($ebp+8+(4*$arg1))     <--- what in does
end

document parg   <--- HERE IS THE COMMENT / DOCUMENTATION ON THIS CUSTOM COMMAND
Prints current function arguments

parg <type> <index>
Prints the <index>th argument of the current function as type <type>
<index> is 0-based
end
```

I know how to add a command in LLDB (command alias ...), but how do I document it?

Answer (score 3):

There isn't any allowance for documenting command aliases -- they're usually pretty straightforward and running 'help' on them will show what they expand to -- but if you define a command in python, you can add documentation to that command.  For instance,

```
(lldb) script
Python Interactive Interpreter. To exit, type 'quit()', 'exit()' or Ctrl-D.
>>> def say_hello(debugger, command, result, dict):
...   print 'hello!'
...   description = '''This command says hello.'''
...   usage = 'usage: say_hello'
... 
>>> ^D
(lldb) command script add -f say_hello say_hello
(lldb) say_hello
hello!
(lldb) help say_hello
   Run Python function say_hello  This command takes 'raw' input (no need to quote stuff).

Syntax: say_hello
(lldb)
```

Note the fourth "..." line where I pressed return on the empty line.

For further information about python scripting in lldb, please see http://lldb.llvm.org/python-reference.html

But no, the answer to your question is that you cannot today document a command alias.

Answer (score 0):

You can document custom lldb commands using docstrings as documented in the [Python Reference](http://lldb.llvm.org/python-reference.html):

> Optionally, you can also provide a Python docstring, and LLDB will use
>   it when providing help for your command, as in:

```
(lldb) script
>>> def documented(*args):
...     '''
...     This command is documented using a docstring.
...
...     You can write anything!
...     '''
...     pass
...
>>> exit
(lldb) command script add -f documented documented
(lldb) help documented

    This command is documented using a docstring.

    You can write anything!

Syntax: documented
(lldb)
```